# How to generate number between a low and a high number using just a bit?

Tags: algorithm, bit-manipulation

I was asked this question in a interview, so I don't want the solution, just the guidance regarding how to approach it.

> You have been given two numbers low and high. And a random generator which generates 0 and 1. I have to generate a number between low and high using that function.

I can get difference between the two numbers and somehow try to generate a number  using bit manipulation. But I am not able to figure out how to do that?

Comment: I fixed a bug in my answer. Sorry about that; I shouldn't have posted it without testing it first. It works ok now. I also added a note about the distribution.

Comment: _low_ being probably too easy, how about _low + (high - low) / 2_?

Comment: @greybeard The question really is about generating random numbers between low and high, but it isn't worded very clearly.

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

1. `range = high - low`
2. find `n` such that `2^n-1 < range <= 2^n`
3. run the random generator n times to generate an int thanks to its binary representation. Something like `010011010` (= 154 in decimal)
4. add the obtained number to `low` to get your final number!

Comment: So after getting n, I should run a while loop where I should generate 1 and 0, and put them on the extreme left? I mean, I have to begin from extreme left ,right?

Comment: It does not matter, right or left. It is a random number so when you think about it, the chosen order is not relevant.

Comment: No what I meant was, while generating a random number, if I start from the right, I can end up generating a number bigger than the difference. on the other hand if I start from the left, I can discard the 1 which makes it bigger and go with zero.

Comment: True. You can come up with any rule in that case. Restart, wrap the number (low + random % range), ...

Comment: @Dude: You are not generating a number. You are generating a random sequence of size 'n' defined in step 2. When you add the equivalent int of that random sequence to the smaller number, you get another number bigger than the smaller but smaller than the bigger number.

Comment: @displayName That is not true, lets say the diff is 1001, our random generator can generate 1101.

Comment: @JeanLogeart: Your solution is correct. The only improvement needed is that the number generated in _step 3_ (in decimal) must be multiplied by _range_ and divided by 2^n. This way you obtain a number between 0 and range, which can be later added to _low_ in _step 4_.

Comment: @Dude: Accessing SO from phone so can't confirm, but in that case the 'n' has been calculated wrong. It should be one less than what we have right now.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a basic bit-by-bit comparison algorithm that gives a random number between low and high, using a random-bit function:

- Decrease `high` by 1 and increase `low` by 1 (in case the random bits introduced later all equal those in `high` or `low`).
- Create booleans `high_dec` and `low_inc` to store whether at least one 1 in `high` has been changed into 0, and at least one 0 in `low` has been changed into 1, and set both of them to false (these will help avoid the result going out of range).
- Compare `high` and `low` bit-by-bit from MSB to LSB with these cases:

  - If you find `high:1` and `low:1` then store a 1 if `low_inc=false` or store a random bit otherwise (and update `high_dec` as necessary).
  - If you find `high:1` and `low:0` then store a random bit (and update    `high_dec` or `low_inc` as necessary).
  - If you find `high:0` and `low:1` then store a 0 if `high_dec=false` or store a 1 if `low_inc=false` or store a random bit otherwise.
  - If you find `high:0` and `low:0` then store a 0 if `high_dec=false` or store a random bit otherwise (and update `low_inc` as necessary).

*Note that the distribution of the random numbers is only uniform if the lowest possible result is a power of 2, and the range is a power of 2. In all cases the whole range is used, but there may be an emphasis on values near the beginning or end of the range.*

```js
function between(a, b) {
    var lo = (a + 1).toString(2).split(''),         // conversion to bit array because
        hi = (b - 1).toString(2).split(''),         // there is no bit manipulation in JS
        lc = false,                                 // low changed
        hc = false,                                 // high changed
        result = [];
    while (lo.length < hi.length) lo.unshift(0);    // add leading zeros to low
    for (var i = 0; i < hi.length; i++) {           // iterate over bits, msb to lsb
        var bit = Math.round(Math.random());        // random bit generator
        if (hi[i] == 1) {
            if (lo[i] == 1) {                       // case hi:1 lo:1
                if (lc == false) bit = 1
                else if (bit == 0) hc = true;
            } else {                                // case hi:1 lo:0
                if (bit == 0) hc = true
                else lc = true;
            }
        } else {
            if (lo[i] == 1) {                       // case hi:0 lo:1
                if (hc == false) bit = 0
                else if (lc == false) bit = 1;
            } else {                                // case hi:0 lo:0
                if (hc == false) bit = 0
                else if (bit == 1) lc = true;
            }
        }
        result.push(bit);
    }
    return parseInt(result.join(''), 2);            // convert bit array to integer
}

document.write(between(999999, 1000100) + "<BR>");
```